# Create table of coordinates from contourplot of equations

Tags: plotting

I have a plot that requires 3 curves. For the plot, [x] is a function of [v].

For each of the curves, I need to find the average [x] value and the average [v] value.

I figured out how to create the plot, but I have no idea how to extract the coordinates so I can get the average. I included the code from mathematical for one of the plots and the generated plot.
[image]

```
p3 = ContourPlot[{v^2/2 + 
     1.01/(1.01 - 1) ((0.7/(v x^2))^(1.01 - 1) - 1) == 1/x, 
   v^2/2 + 1.01/(1.01 - 1) ((1.092/(v x^2))^(1.01 - 1) - 1) == 1/x, 
   v^2/2 + 1.01/(1.01 - 1) ((1.3/(v x^2))^(1.01 - 1) - 1) == 1/x}, {x,
    0.2, 2}, {v, 0.2, 2.5}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{"\[Lambda]<\[Lambda]c", "\[Lambda]=\[Lambda]c", 
     "\[Lambda]>\[Lambda]c"}, {0.8, 0.5}], 
  PlotLabel -> Style["\[Gamma]=1.01", Blue, 20], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Try this: `Cases[Normal@ p3, Line[pts_] :> pts, All]`

Comment: What is the average of a curve? Do you mean `RegionCentroid`?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2424260).

Comment: `Cases[Normal@p3, Line[pts_] :> Mean[pts], All]`?

Comment: @MarcoB yes! that worked! now is there anyway to find the average X value and V value from the coordinates?